# Currency switch rewrite does not preserve querystring

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, currency

Magento version 1.9.4

We are using Magento currency switcher URLs, and we need to add some query string at end, but when it resolves the rewrite, the querystring is gone.

Ex:

```
https://www.website.com/directory/currency/switch/currency/DKK/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGVyZnVtZXNwcmVtaXVtLmNvbS9pbmRleC5waHAvc2hpbW1lcmluZy1jcmVhbS1leWUtY29sb3ItZ3IxMjUtbmFpYWQtNi1ncg?key=value
```

Resolves to:

```
https://www.website.com/index.php/some-product-page
```

While we would like to have:

```
https://www.website.com/index.php/some-product-page?key=value
```

We've been looking around and found this:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento-Redirect-Loses-URL-Querystring/m-p/4773#M1163

But it does not seem to apply, since the URL there seems to have already been rewritten, and querystring is nowhere to be found.

Is there a way to modify currency url rewrite so that it preserves querystring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record,

In the end I accomplished what I wanted using some rewrites in htaccess.

Doing what I wanted to do here should have needed some changes in the router (I guess), and I'm not so well versed in Magento to do such a big change :-)

Thanks anyway.